# How to connect to a dll in Delphi that has such functions?

Tags: c++, delphi

Here are the c++ functions

```
#ifdef LOGGER_EXPORTS
#define LOGGER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LOGGER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" LOGGER_API void LogMessage(const json& message);

extern "C" LOGGER_API std::vector<json> getCommands();

extern "C" LOGGER_API void CreateLogger(const std::string& infilename, const std::string& outfilename, const std::string& idinfilename, const std::string& idoutfilename);

extern "C" LOGGER_API void CreateLoggerWithLogs(const std::string& infilename, const std::string& outfilename, const std::string& idinfilename, const std::string& idoutfilename,
    const std::string& logInput, const std::string& logOutput);
```

After connecting the library in c ++, I use this notation

`CreateLoggerWithLogs(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], logsInput, logsOutput);`
Everything works well.

I don't understand how I can cast the types. In addition, when we call CreateLogger, we create a static instance of the class. Will it live, as in C++, before I call the destructor?

In Delphi, I declare functions like this:

```
procedure LogMessage(const message: TJSONObject); cdecl;
  external 'ConnectionDLL.dll';

function getCommands(): TJSONObject; cdecl; external 'ConnectionDLL.dll';

procedure CreateLogger(const infilename, outfilename, idinfilename,
  idoutfilename: PAnsiChar); cdecl; external 'ConnectionDLL.dll';

procedure CreateLoggerWithLogs(const infilename, outfilename, idinfilename,
  idoutfilename, logInput, logOutput: PAnsiChar); cdecl;
  external 'ConnectionDLL.dll';
```

And I call:

```
var
  infilename, outfilename, idinfilename, idoutfilename, logInput, logOutput: PAnsiChar;
begin
    infilename := 'input_filename';
    outfilename := 'output_filename';
    idinfilename := 'id_input_filename';
    idoutfilename := 'id_output_filename';
    logInput := 'log_input_filename';
    logOutput := 'log_output_filename';

    CreateLoggerWithLogs(infilename, outfilename, idinfilename, idoutfilename,
      logInput, logOutput);
end;
```

And inevitably I get an error "External exception" when calling `CreateLoggerWithLogs`.
If a library works well in a C++ application, then it's not the problem. I think I'm passing the parameters wrong. I think these are types. It would be nice to somehow debug the c++ library with delphi code.

Comment: You can't, you can't use non trivial c++ classes when interfacing with other languages

Comment: Even other implementations of C++ may not be able to use the DLL. Consider for example the implementation you are using defines `std::string` with a 32 byte short string optimization (SSO) buffer, a pointer to the string data (that may be pointing to the SSO buffer) and a bit of other book-keeping tracking the length of the string and the buffer capacity. But the implementers of the library compiled against a C++Standard Library implementation that uses a union of the SSO buffer and the longer string tracking information.

Comment: The `string`s you pass into the library functions will look nothing like the strings the library expects to receive and the resulting behaviour could be a nice, polite crash, or it could be utterly soul-crushing days of debugging insane outputs. The general recommendation is to present a C language interface to the users of the DLL.

Comment: how should i pass and declare strings?

Comment: @Alan Birtles
 can't I use this library?

Comment: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html

Comment: @AgniusIgres The C++ functions you have presented are NOT PORTABLE across different compilers, and are NOT COMPATIBLE with Delphi at all. If you need to use this DLL with Delphi, you have no choice but to use a compatible C++ compiler to wrap these functions inside of new functions that are usable with C-compatible languages, including Delphi.

Comment: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html